# Using cloud code to monitor for new users and conditionally add them to ACL

Tags: parse-platform

Suppose that through a Parse app, user A sends Facebook friend B an invitation to join him in editing object O (e.g., participating in an ongoing conversation).

B is notified of this via Facebook, but because he has not signed up for the app and therefore does not yet exist as a PFUser, A cannot add him to O's ACL.

However, when B signs up in the future, he should immediately be given write access to object O. He cannot add himself on the client side because he does not have write permission. Therefore this must be achieved on the back end.

Question: What would the cloud code look like that accomplished the following:

1. whenever a new PFUser is created, trigger a check for the presence of a particular string in an array of strings (i.e., for the presence of that user's facebookID in an array of facebookID strings)
2. if a match is found, give this new user write permission for the ACL on PFObject O

(I don't have any experience with java script/cloud code, so example code would be very helpful in starting to get my bearings.)

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Could Code you can tell it to use the master key, so it can bypass the normal restrictions.

I would expect it would be a multiple step process:

- user A invites friend B, this would create an InvitationToEdit record linked to user A, object O and include something to help us identify friend B (facebook ID, email, or some token)
- when friend B signs up, that identifying information would be used to activate pending invitations

The Cloud Code would have access to `request.user` as the newly invited friend, and the identifier used. It could then search for all InvitationToEdit records and for each one add the `request.user` to the ACL of the object O.

Many systems that do stuff like this generate a GUID as the token for a single invite, and the page to accept the invite will let them either log in or register. Once complete the single token is processed and discarded. Usually there is some kind of expiry on tokens (e.g. a couple of days).

**UPDATE:** (with links)

You can learn about writing [Cloud Code functions](https://parse.com/docs/cloud_code_guide#functions). Essentially the contents of those functions is just JavaScript, so the docs on [Updating Objects](https://parse.com/docs/js_guide#objects-updating) would be worth reading, as well as the rest of the docs.

Comment: Cool, an answer! That method makes sense and I've got a pretty good idea of the algorithm I want to use. I just dove into Cloud Code yesterday and I'm hung up on something pretty basic: Could you provide a simple code example of how to edit a value for an object existing in the Parse database? Like suppose I have queried for a "Student" object and obtained a reference for it (I've accomplished that much), and now I want to change the value for its key "Grade" and save that change to the database. Do you know how to do that kind of thing?? Thanks!

Comment: Added some links to the docs to explain what you wanted to know. If my answer helps, don't forget to tick it as the correct answer.